# How to make GridLines Dashed in D3 without separate css file?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I have some code like this, and I want to style the `innerTickSize` portion to make it the gridlines dashed or solid dynamically how should I go about doing so, without using an external css just D3 to style it.

```js
var x = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var y = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('line') 
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
```

Comment: This dashes the Axis not the grid lines :(

Comment: @jamestwiggle can you post a jsfiddle? so i can check it out?